# Accessing API from outside the on-premises Service Fabric cluster

Tags: rest, azure-service-fabric, api-gateway

I am very new to Service Fabric. We are developing an API to run inside a Service Fabric cluster. In production we have a 3 virtual machine cluster. In DEV & UAT, we connect the API directly with the server name, as it is a single PC server. I want to run the API in all 3 nodes, and introduce a API gateway running on top. The gateway will do a bit of load balancing as well. Again, the gateway API will run in a single node and from outside I don't know which node it is running on. How should I communicate to the gateway?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Zubi Rabbi

Comment: you should take a look to this answer, is very similar issue to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155210/service-fabric-load-balancer-tweak-needed-or-not/52171081#52171081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce an external [Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule) (like Azure Load Balancer) on top of your cluster, to receive and forward traffic to (healthy) cluster services.

I do recommend to run your gateway on all nodes, so it doesn't matter which node you talk to. This increases availability and performance.

Comment: Hi Loek, thanks for your suggestion. I understand what you are suggesting. Need little bit clarification. I have a url: https://myapi.com.au/api. And the API Getway running in three node on same port. Now I have a load balancer in place and my url point to that. Load balancer will automatically point to any of the three node? what happen if any of the node is down.
Regards,
Zubi

Comment: Hi Loek, Is there any virtual IP for service fabric cluster?

Comment: - health of services is monitored by using health probes. If a service stops responding, it will be taken out of circulation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-create-basic-load-balancer-powershell#create-a-health-probe

Comment: - you can configure the load balancer with a public ip address https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-create-basic-load-balancer-portal

Comment: Hi Loek, network team introduce LoadBalancer on top to service fabric and issue is resolved.